# How to get the ConstructorInfo of a Ctor with params

Tags: c#, reflection, constructor, system.reflection, system.type

I am trying to write code that receives an argument list and gets the ConstructorInfo of a matching Ctor.

The method signature is `ConstructorInfo GetConstructorInfo(Type type, object[] args)`.

I have created a class to work with:

```
public class ClassWithParamsInCtor
{
    public ClassWithParamsInCtor(params int[] parameters)
    {

    }
}
```

Using the `Activator` class I can create instances of this object:

```
ClassWithParamsInCtor myclass = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(ClassWithParamsInCtor), new object[] { 1,2 }) as ClassWithParamsInCtor; \\returns a valid instance of the class;
```

But when I try to get the ConstructorInfo there is an issue, the following returns null:

```
ConstructorInfo ctorInfo = typeof(ClassWithParamsInCtor).GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(int), typeof(int) }); \\returns null
```

How can I obtain the ConstructorInfo in such a case ?

Answer (score 5):

`params int[]` is a syntactic sugar for `int[]`, you need to use `typeof(int[])`

```
typeof(ClassWithParamsInCtor).GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(int[]) });
```

Comment: Thanks Selman! This does help in the above case, but I still have an issue. I have explained the issue in more details in the comment I made to Berkay, I would appreciate further help

Comment: @Belgi when ur method takes `double` and `params int[]` use `new Type[] { typeof(double), typeof(int[]) }`

Comment: The problem is that I don't know in advance how to deconstruct the object[] that I'm  receiving, it is a general piece of code meant to called for different types

Comment: @Belgi hmm, in that case, can you try this to get type array: `args.Select(x => x.GetType()).ToArray();` and pass it to `GetConstructor` but this wont work for params ofc. when you pass two ints it will return two `typeof(int)`, you need to handle params specifically, since the params defined at the end of parameter list, check if the args contains same type of arguments at the end, like if it's `double, string, int, int, int` you can check if there is a constructor that takes double, string and int[] array

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
ConstructorInfo ctorInfo = typeof(ClassWithParamsInCtor).GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(int[])});
```

Hope helps,

Comment: Thanks Berkay! this helps, but there is still an issue when this isn't the only argument the ctor has. For example if the Ctor got a double x and params int[] args and my method was passed an object[] that was [3.5 ,1 ,2]. I can start matching arguments greedily if they are of type int, but I hope there is a better way

Answer (score 2):

I think that I have a solution for your problem if I understood it right.

Assuming you have the following class :

```
 public class ClassWithParamsInCtor
    {
        public ClassWithParamsInCtor(params int[] parameters)
        {

        }
        public ClassWithParamsInCtor(int[] parameters, double y)
        {

        }

        public ClassWithParamsInCtor(int[] parameters, float y)
        {

        }
    }
```

Here are some Unit Tests that describe the solution that I've implemented :

```
 [TestClass]
    public class TestClassWithParamsInCtorClass
    {
        [TestMethod]
        //Wrong data type test
        public void WrongInputDataTypesTest()
        {
            //Arrange
            var inputData = new object[] { new[] { 1, 2 }, "" };
            var inputDataTypes = inputData.Select(_ => _.GetType());

            //Act
            var matchedCtorParams = typeof(ClassWithParamsInCtor)
                                   .GetConstructors()
                                   .Select(_ => _.GetParameters().Select(a => a.ParameterType))
                                   .Where(_ => _.HaveSameItems(inputDataTypes)).ToArray();

            //Assert 
            Assert.AreEqual(null, matchedCtorParams.FirstOrDefault());
        }

        [TestMethod]
        //Test used to invoke first constructor
        public void InputDataTypesTest1()
        {
            //Arrange
            var inputData = new object[] { new[] { 1, 2 } , 1 };
            var inputDataTypes = inputData.Select(_ => _.GetType());

            //Act
            var matchedCtorParams = typeof(ClassWithParamsInCtor)
                                   .GetConstructors()
                                   .Select(_ => _.GetParameters().Select(a => a.ParameterType))
                                   .Where(_ => _.HaveSameItems(inputDataTypes)).ToArray();

           var result = typeof(ClassWithParamsInCtor).GetConstructor(matchedCtorParams.FirstOrDefault().ToArray())
                   .Invoke(inputData);

            //Assert 
            Assert.AreNotEqual(null, result);

        }

        [TestMethod]
        //Test used to invoke second constructor
        public void InputDataTypesTest2()
        {
            //Arrange
            var inputData = new object[] { new[] { 1, 2 }, 1.2 };
            var inputDataTypes = inputData.Select(_ => _.GetType());

            //Act
            var matchedCtorParams = typeof(ClassWithParamsInCtor)
                                   .GetConstructors()
                                   .Select(_ => _.GetParameters().Select(a => a.ParameterType))
                                   .Where(_ => _.HaveSameItems(inputDataTypes)).ToArray();

            var result = typeof(ClassWithParamsInCtor).GetConstructor(matchedCtorParams.FirstOrDefault().ToArray())
                    .Invoke(inputData);

            //Assert 
            Assert.AreNotEqual(null, result);

        }

        [TestMethod]
        //Test used to invoke third constructor
        public void InputDataTypesTest3()
        {
            //Arrange
            var inputData = new object[] { new[] { 1, 2 }, 3.5F };
            var inputDataTypes = inputData.Select(_ => _.GetType());

            //Act
            var matchedCtorParams = typeof(ClassWithParamsInCtor)
                                   .GetConstructors()
                                   .Select(_ => _.GetParameters().Select(a => a.ParameterType))
                                   .Where(_ => _.HaveSameItems(inputDataTypes)).ToArray();

            var result = typeof(ClassWithParamsInCtor).GetConstructor(matchedCtorParams.FirstOrDefault().ToArray())
                    .Invoke(inputData);

            //Assert 
            Assert.AreNotEqual(null, result);

        }
    }
```

And the extension method that I used :

```
 public static bool HaveSameItems<T>(this IEnumerable<T> a, IEnumerable<T> b)
        {
            var dictionary = a.GroupBy(x => x).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
            foreach (var item in b)
            {
                int value;
                if (!dictionary.TryGetValue(item, out value))
                {
                    return false;
                }
                if (value == 0)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                dictionary[item] -= 1;
            }
            return dictionary.All(x => x.Value == 0);
        }
```

I'm pretty sure that the Unit tests can be implemented to be more granular specific, but considering this as a proofe of concept, I find them decent.